# Using Wordpress add_rewrite_rule with Polylang plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I am using this code to add rewrite_rule for Wordpress to create Child posts For another post type

```
add_action( 'init', function() {add_rewrite_rule( '^property/(.*)/units/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?property_units=$matches[2]','top' );});

add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $link, $post ) {
  if ( 'property_units' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
    if( $post->post_parent ) {
      $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
      if( !empty($parent->post_name) ) {return str_replace( '%property_name%', $parent->post_name, $link );}
    }
  }
  return $link;
}, 10, 2 );
```

And it works well

But when i add Polylang plugin, it only works with the default language and does not work for other languages

Answer (score 0):

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^property/(.*)/units/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?property_units=$matches[2]','top' )
```

need to add `?lang=en` to the url

Answer (score 0):

My PolyLang settings was set to use **language from directory name**, **hide default language** and **remove `/language` in permalink**.

I use this code for custom URI/URL that runs independent (not based on post or page) and it can work with URLs `/custompage`, `/en/custompage`.

```php
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-zA-Z]{0,2}/?)custompage/?$', 'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&custompage=index', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-zA-Z]{0,2}/?)custompage/my?$', 'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&custompage=my-custompage', 'top');

add_rewrite_tag('%custompage%', '([^&]+)');
```

For custom URL/URL based on post or page.
I've created page with certain slug (`custompage`) and translated into languages with PolyLang. I use the code below. The `postIds` is all post IDs that are translated for certain page.
Example **หน้ากำหนดเอง** is in Thai and ID 166, **custompage** is in English and ID 167. The IDs will be `array(166, 167)`.

```php
foreach ($postIds as $postId) {
    $Post = get_post($postId);
    if (!is_object($Post)) {
        continue;
    }

    add_rewrite_rule('^([a-zA-Z]{0,2}/?)' . $Post->post_name . '/my/?$', 'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&pagename=' . $Post->post_name . '&custompage=my-custompage', 'top');
    unset($Post);
}// endforeach;

add_rewrite_tag('%custompage%', '([^&]+)');
```

I have to add rules for all of the post's translations at once, otherwise it won't work.

Don't forget to save permalink in WordPress settings page to flush the rewrite rules before test.